# Neo4j read_only doesn't work

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

So... I know there's quite a few articles and stuff to read about how to set Neo4j in read-only mode. Problem is, it doesn't seem to work for me.

I've got an existing database in Neo4j 3.0.3 (I'm not the one who put it together though, so I'm really no expert) and I need to start in a way, that only read-access is allowed.

I tried changing the neo4j.conf file accordingly (some sources say to put "read_only=true", others "dbms.shell.read_only=true") but I'm still able to delete or add nodes and relations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the configuration for read only in neo4j.conf:

```
# Only allow read operations from this Neo4j instance. This mode still requires
# write access to the directory for lock purposes.
dbms.read_only=true
```

Reference: http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#config_dbms.read_only